# Im a newbie at python but how do i get the first value of precipitation, temperature, wind_gust and humidity?

Tags: python, arrays, list, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/weather/forecast/gcvwr3zrw#?date=2020-07-12")

time.sleep(5)

precipitation = driver.find_element_by_class_name("step-pop")
print(precipitation.text)

temperature = driver.find_element_by_class_name("step-temp")
print(temperature.text)

wind_gust = driver.find_element_by_class_name("step-wind-gust")
print(wind_gust.text)

humidity = driver.find_element_by_class_name("step-humidity")
print(humidity.text)
```

Output

```
50% 10% 10% 30% 20% 10% 10% 10% 10% 20% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% <5% <5% <5% <5% <5%
15°
15°
16°
15°
15°
15°
15°
15°
15°
15°
16°
16°
16°
16°
17°
17°
17°
17°
17°
16°
15°
14°
13°
12°
18 20 26 24 23 23 24 23 22 22 23 26 26 25 26 26 26 28 28 27 27 24 22 22
71% 74% 77% 81% 82% 82% 85% 88% 87% 84% 74% 71% 74% 71% 69% 67% 65% 65% 62% 63% 63% 66% 69% 74%
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what you need to give us so we can help, and then edit your question with *details of the problem* you are having, *what you have already tried yourself* to solve it and your relevant code in a [*minimal, reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using xpath to extract that data:

```
humidity = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@class="detailed-view step-humidity"]//span[@class="humidity"][@data-type="percentage"]')
temperature = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@class="step-temp"][@data-type="temp"]//td[@data-temp]/div')
precipitation = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@class="step-pop"]//td[@class]')
wind_gust = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@class="detailed-view step-wind-gust"]//td/span[@class="gust"]')

for h in humidity:
    print(h.get_attribute('data-value'))
for t in temperature:
    print(t.text)
for p in precipitation:
    print(p.text)
for w in wind_gust:
    print(w.text)
```

Since in cases like this xpath is the best targeting approach, and - on the other hand - selenium's xpath support is rather limited, I usually just hand over `page_source` to a library like lxml and parse it there.

I would also just load everything into a pandas dataframe after this is all done.

Edit:

To get only the first element of each weather feature, use:

```
print(humidity[0].get_attribute('data-value'),temperature[0].text,precipitation[0].text)
```

Comment: I tried this but it throws up an error 
File "D:/Computing/Python/Testing/Weather Test.py", line 13, in <module>
    temperature = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@class="step-temp"][@data-type="temp"]//td[@data-temp]/div')
NameError: name 'browser' is not defined

Comment: @Nathan03999 Sorry, it was a typo; -`broswer` should have been `driver`; see edit.

Comment: Ah ok, ive done that but the output appears to have random numbers at the start of it:
70
74
71
63
65
65
66
70
75
76
78
80
81
82
82
81
78
73
69
63
61
59
58
57
54
55
57
62
68
74
77
81
83
84
87
89
88
79
75
70
72
79
85
88
87
76
71
68
75
85
89
90
87
75
69
70
73
81
83
87
86
71
64
64
67
76
84
85
85
71
58
58
61
72

Comment: @Nathan03999 These aren't random numbers. The line in your comment is a list of humidity levels; next line should start `18°
16°
16°
17°
16°
16°` for temperature, etc.

Comment: Oh my bad, it was in a different order and i got confused lol, so how would i go about getting the first value for humidity, precipitation etc?

Comment: @Nathan03999 What do you mean by "first value"? Do you want to get only `70` from humidity, `18°` form temperature, etc.?

Comment: Ye thats what i mean, im going to use the values to make a formula

Comment: Ah thanks a lot for the help man, really appreciate it